# Jenkins pipeline trigger on file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run jenkins pipeline every 5 minutes and trigger stages only if /tmp/*.json exists. How to do that ?

I have the skeleton :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        def JSON_PATH = '/tmp/*.json'
    }

    triggers {
        cron('*/5 * * * *')
    }

    stages {
        [...]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. To check file existence, you can use `ls` and read the exit status.

```
stage('Check file existence') {
    steps {
        script {
            fileExists = sh(returnStatus: true, script: 'ls /tmp/*.json') == 0
        }
    }
}

stage('Do actions') {
    when {
        expression { fileExists }
    }
    steps {
        <insert desired steps here>
    }
}
```